# How to save all variables (not only net variables) to be able to resume training when using custom training loops in TF2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am using a custom training loop to train a `Model` in TF2. I want to be able to save the state of my optimization at a given moment to be able to restart it later on. The variables to be saved are the model parameters, but also optimization variables, and a couple of other variables lying here and there.

In TF1, this was actually not even a question because [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/Saver) would save all variables by default.

Now, how to do that in TF2?

According to the guide, in TF2, saving is done via the functionality exposed by Keras, either using specific callbacks or `Model` methods. Both methods *can* save more that just net parameters, but to be able to achieve this, the model needs to be compiled using `tf.Model.compile` so that everythins is bundled together. However, with custom training loops, there is precisely no call to `compile`.

So how to save all my variables to be able to resume training when one is not using the Right Path of `compile`/`fit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.train.Checkpoint` and put all variables that you want to save to this function.

```
tf.train.Checkpoint(model=model, optimizer=optimizer, [xx=xx])
```

more detail please see this [tf.train.Checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint?version=stable)